# Using gnuplot instead of excel to plot ping responses

Tags: gnuplot

I have a set of data from ping composed of a time stamp and the time, in ms, of the ping response.  The time stamp ranges from 08:29:42 and ends at 09:33:54.  There is a comma between the time stamp and the ping response.  Here is a sample of the actual file:

```
08:29:42, 4.24

08:29:43, 117

08:29:44, 141

08:29:45, 266

08:29:46, 292

08:29:47, 109
```

When importing the text file into Excel and highlighting columns A and B and inserting a line chart, I get the following:

[excel graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3mWL.png)

It is desirable to stay away from Excel and I was hoping to employ gnuplot for this.  Specifically because the ping data was collected by a bash script and I could add in the gnuplot functionality to the same script in order to automate things.

Taking the same file and loading it into gnuplot with the following commands:

```
set term png

set out "gnuplot graph.png"

plot 'ping.txt' with lines
```

I get the following output:

[gnuplot graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYoIQ.png)

I do not see near the detail in the gnuplot that I see in the excel plot.  Additionally the time on the X-Axis only ranges from 08:00-09:00.  I would like the graph to take in the entire range from the text file and plot appropriately.

What am I doing wrong in gnuplot for the outputs to be so different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gnuplot doesn't know that the x data you are using is a time unless you tell it that. Try the following script instead.

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%H:%M:%S"
plot "ping.txt" using 1:2
```

Edit:

To use lines instead of points add `with lines` to the end of your plot command:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%H:%M:%S"
plot "ping.txt" using 1:2 with lines
```

Also I noticed that the data you put in your question has empty lines separating the data points. This will cause your lines to not show up. I highly recommend reformatting your CSV to remove the blank lines.

Comment: the format should be `"%H:%M:%S"`, i.e. hours, minutes, seconds...

Comment: @theozh Thanks for the correction, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you.  Your suggestion got me on the road.  Here are the file tweaks to my gnuplot commands: "set xdata time; set timefmt '%H:%M:%S'; set term png; set term png size 2048,786; set xtics rotate; set xtics 60; plot 'infile.txt' using 1:2 with lines"